# Should I install Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 20.04 to be able to use Android Studio and resolve similar compatibility issues?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, 20.04, java, android-studio

So I've been meaning to do some Android Development so I wanted to install Android Studio, and a prerequisite for that is to have installed Oracle JDK, but they have no releases for Focal Fossa.

So, should I switch to Ubuntu 18.04 instead and then upgrade to 20.04 when there's an Oracle JDK for it?

I've encountered many such problems on the way. Should I switch to 18.04 to resolve this type of issue? (Or should i may be switch to some other distro)?

PS. I am very new to Linux OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu only includes Open Source JDK alternatives in its repositories, whether it is 18.04 or 20.04. Oracle does not allow even downloading its JDK anymore without a user account since 2019.

Either install e.g. the openjdk-11-jdk package that is in the repositories, or install Azul Systems OpenJDK following [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/install-latest-openjdk-12-11-or-8-in.html) guide.

For any other problems you might have with 20.04, please post specific questions (or look for answers that are already there).